# Eclipse Properties View without IAdaptable

Tags: eclipse, view, properties, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I tried to create a properties view for a graph model in an Eclipse RCP Application. The graph elements are from a non-eclipse library and so don't implement IAdaptable or even IPropertySource.

The Tabbed Properties View, explained here:
http://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-Tabbed-Properties/tabbed_properties_view.html
seems to be a simple possibility - but only for inputs that implement IAdaptable.

I've thought about implementing my own IPropertySheetPage but the only implementations I found are the built-in PropertySheetPage and TabbedPropertySheetPage which are very complex.

Is there another way to create a properties view for input elements that don't implement IAdaptable? Can I use Tabbed Properties View in a way I don't see yet? Are there any other less complex implementations of IPropertySheetPage, I can look at?

Thank you!

Kristina

Answer (score 2):

Actually, you can write an `IAdapterFactory` for objects which don't implement `IAdaptable` and register it in `plugin.xml` or in your plugin activator. See http://www.eclipsezone.com/eclipse/forums/t61666.html.

Answer (score 1):

> Are there any other less complex implementations of IPropertySheetPage, I can look at?

Short answer: No.

But why don't you wrap the non-adaptable object into your own object that implements IAdaptable or IPropertySource or whatever, so that the property-page can work with your wrapper which holds the object you want to make editable through the property-page. And instead of providing this "library" object to global adapter-mechanism, create the wrapper, set the object and provide it to your global selection-service or whatever.

Comment: Thank you for the advice. If I don't find another solution, I will try it. But there are other elements working with the selection that I would have to change too. So I would prefer a way that doesn't affect the rest of the program.